# Unable to fetch package information for 'library@latest': Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular12

`angular 12` add library is giving bellow error

> Unable to fetch package information for 'library@latest': Cannot convert undefined or null to object

detail error message:

```
 ℹ Using package manager: npm
 ✖ Unable to find compatible package.  Using 'latest'.
 ✖ Unable to fetch package information for 'library@latest': Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

steps to reproduce

```
ng new newProject
ng add library @namespace/libname
```

Answer (score -1):

**The command is `generate` not `add`!**

The mistake was I was doing `add` rather `generate`. To add an library in an existing project, you need to do `generate` rather `add`

correct syntax:

`ng generate library @candypal/website`